# Creating a DLL with a different C++ environment

Tags: c++, dll, c++11, linker, c++03

I have a library I'm building which is targeted to be a DLL that is linked into the main solution.

This new DLL is quite complex and I'd like to make use of C++11 features, while the program that will link it most certainly does not. In fact, the main program is currently "cleanly" built using VS2008 and VS2010 (and i think GCC 4.3 for linux?).

What I propose:

Using VS2012 as the IDE and Intel C++ Compiler 2013 for compilation to .dll/.so - for linux - which, as I understand, is basically down to machine form (like an .exe).

While I'm familiar with using C++ to solve problems, I am not fluent in the fundamentals of compilation/linking, etc. Therefore, I'd like to ask the community if

1. This is possible
2. If it is possible, how easy is it (as simple as I described?) / what pitfalls or issues can I expect along the way (is it worth it)?

Areas of concern I anticipate:

- runtime libraries - I expect this to be the factor that derails this effort. I know nothing about them/how they work except that they might be a problem.
- Standard Library implementation differences - should it matter if it's down to DLL form?
- threading conflicts - the dll threads and the main programs threads never modify the same data, and actually one of the main program's threads will call the DLL functions.

Bonus: While the above is the route I expect to take, I'd ideally like to have this code open for intellisense, general viewing, etc (essentially for it to become a project in the main solution). Is there a way to specify different runtime libraries/compiler? Can this be done?

**EDIT**: The main reason for this bonus part is to eliminate the necessary "versioning" conflicts that will arise if the main program and this library are built separately.

NOTE: I'm not using C++11 just for the sake of being newer - strongly typed enums and cross-platform threading code will be huge bonuses for the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question isn't so much "Can an application use a library built with a different compiler ?" (The answer is yes.) but "What C++ features can be used in the public interface of a library built with another compiler and C++ standard library?"

On Windows, the answer is "almost none".  Interfaces (classes containing only virtual functions) are about it.  No classes with data members.  No exceptions.  No runtime objects (like iostream instances or strings).  No templates.

On Linux, the answer is "lots more but still not many".  Classes are ok, as long as the ODR is satisfied.  Exceptions will work.  Templates too, as long as the definition is exactly the same on both sides.  But definitions of standard library types did change between C++03 and C++11, so you won't for example be able to pass `std::string` or `std::vector<int>` objects between the application and library (both sides can use these features, but the same object can't cross over).

Comment: :/ So i guess for a cross-platform, C++11 coded piece, I'd have to convince the entire solution to migrate to ICC2013 then, huh meetings yay. (On that note, is migrating the compiler sufficient? Anything else I'd need to consider?)

Comment: @AK4749: The other thing besides the compiler is to make sure you don't violate the One Definition Rule.  So if you have options for calling convention or to enable debug iterators or anything similar that might change class layout, make sure those are set identically across all modules.  Then, you need to make sure that memory isn't freed with a different allocator than the one it came from.

Comment: ah yeah, I *think* I've taken allocation into account. All memory allocated by this library is entirely owned by this library so that should be okay. I'll take a closer look at your other points for sure. ICC2013 should come with all the libraries/etc that are required for end-to-end C++11 executable then, is what I'm reading here. Is that correct? And would the execution environment need newer runtime libraries that are *incompatible* side-by-side with the older ones? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @AK4749: Yes, what I meant to emphasize is that ICC2013 may come with more than one runtime library (often release and debug versions).  Make sure you're using the same one in all modules.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this is not possible with C++. Especially name mangling can be different. All C++ files linked together need to be compiled with same compiler.

In C++, `extern "C"` stuff is standard (naming, calling convention), so C libraries can be called from C++, as well as C++ functions declared withing `extern "C"` block. This exludes classes, templates, overloads, mixing them compiled by different compilers is not workable.

Which is a pity.

Comment: Libraries built in different compilers are compatible if they meet at a C interface.  But that doesn't mean they have to be written in C.  You can write C++ code that exports a public C interface.  Also,  platforms other than Windows sometimes define a standard C++ ABI, making use of a C++ interface compatible also.

Comment: Also "you can make a trivial test" isn't a very good suggestion in this case.  A trivial test might work, but that doesn't mean there won't be problems with inheritance, or when you enable optimizations, etc.

Comment: @BenVoigt , hyde : Ah bollocks, thanks for the info you two. Got a slight rush reading the C-compatible interface, when I realized i have tons of classes, templates AND overloads to export haha I suppose I'll have to make a technical case to skip the VS2010 migration then and move straight to 2012 if I want this library to use any important C++11 features then. Thanks for the info